# What are "entry points" and "exit points" when referred to reverse engineering?

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, in-app-billing

The tips in the [Security and Design](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_best_practices.html) document for Android's In-app Billing state that:

> In particular, attackers look for known *entry points* and *exit
>   points* in an application, so it is important that you modify these
>   parts of your code that are identical to the sample application.

Since I am going to use In-app Billing for the first time, I am very much interested in understanding what this means exactly, in terms of securing my subscription-based app:

1. What are exactly those "known entry/exit points"?
2. What do I need to modify in these parts, to make the task of an
   attacker more difficult?
3. Given the fact that nothing can be protected from eventual reverse-engineering, is it really worth it to go to such great length to protect an
   application/service?

Comment: This might shed some light: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Application_Threat_Modeling#Entry_Points

Comment: @Jason Down +1 already. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that document is talking about the methods that are standard in Android for starting an application, namely the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) methods (`onCreate`, etc.). These are easy for attackers to find because they aren't obfuscated (since the framework needs to be able to find them).

Comment: +1 for being specific, which helps me focus on the target which is, indeed, Android-specific.

Answer (score 3):

> Given the fact that nothing can be protected from eventual
>   reverse-engineering, is it really worth it to go to such great length
>   to protect an application/service?

This is indeed an interesting question! To answer it one also has to ask: What is the expected cost of *not* protecting the app?

If the items sold via IAP incurr an actual cost for the provider/developer (think for instance of selling MP3s where for each download the provider might have to pay a license fee himself) this becomes even more important. This usually indicates the the possible win for an adversary and, thus, the effort he may be willing to invest in reverse engineering.

However, my impression is that there is only a marginal "black market" for cracked/pirated/... apps, the rationale being that it is not possible to offer those cracks or cracked apps via Google's market, which is the only one that comes pre-installed on all Android phones. Regular users will never see any other source of apps.

So, if you expect to sell a bigger volume of your app, you might well live with, say, 1% fraud by "power users". If your app is somewhat special and pricey and you expect to sell only a couple dozens or hundreds, you will be more interested in securing your intellectual property.

The first step in securing will always be obfuscation, which will take your app's security pretty far with (almost) no additional effort on your side. I recommend to obfuscate *every* app published if there are no strong reasons against it (stacktraces, for instance, may become completely useless in an obfuscated app).

Answer (score 2):

At a fairly basic high level, entry points are where the application is started and exit points are where it ends. Each of these (as mentioned above) are unprotected and also tend to make some calls which aren't made anywhere else, making them easy to find and change.